# Scraping eBay Sold Items using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape sold items on eBay. I'm trying to scrape:

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720

Here is my code where I load in html code and convert to soup object:

```
    ebay_url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=oakley+sunglasses&_sacat=0&Brand=Oakley&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_ipg=200&_oaa=1&_fsrp=1&_dcat=79720'
    response = requests.get(ebay_url)

    soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
```

I'm working on getting the titles, prices, and date sold and then loading it into a csv file. Here is the code I have for the titles:

```
    title = soup.find_all("h3", "s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags")
    print(title)

    listing_titles = []

    for i in range(1,len(title)):
    listing_titles.append(title[i].text)

    print(listing_titles)
```

Which just returns empty square braces like []. The html soup object prints correctly, and the response prints as 200. It seems that my code should work, and that finding the post price and sale date should be similar. I'm wondering if this is a job for selenium. Hopefully someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

First you can find all div based on class and loop over it get title,price and date

```
main_data=soup.find_all("div",class_="s-item__info clearfix")[1:]
for i in main_data:
    print(i.find("span",class_="POSITIVE").get_text())
    print(i.find("h3",class_="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags").get_text())
    print(i.find("span",class_="s-item__price").get_text())
```

Output:

```
Sold  Aug 15, 2021
Oakley A Wire 2.0  Sunglasses Brushed Thick Frames Green Lenses
$185.00
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I put this into a new jupyter notebook cell after I load in URL response then convert to soup object, it still returns nothing. I will put my code in the main question.

Comment: are you able to open URL in chrome?

Comment: I should be able to do it, not sure how. Are you talking about using python to open the chrome url?

Comment: manually open your url in chrome and also `print(response.status_code)`  for confirmation

Comment: I manually opened the url in chrome, and the response.status_code returned 200. Still not printing anything. Do I have to use selenium for this?

Comment: Using selenium I was able to open the link in chrome

Comment: Yes try combination of  `selenium` and `bs4` for sure you will able to get output!

Comment: I created another thread using selenium. Can you take a look and possibly comment on that, or could you adjust this answer? Not sure how to combine bs4 and selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The response may be empty because the `requests` request may be blocked, since the default `user-agent` in the `requests` library is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/89c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) to tell the website that it is a bot or script that is sending the request. [Check what user agent you have](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

An additional step besides providing browser user-agent could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on.

It is also possible to fetch [all results from all pages using pagination](https://dimitryzub.medium.com/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#5a11), the solution to this would be to use an infinite `while` loop and test for something (button, element) that will cause it to exit.

In our case, this is the presence of a button on the page (`.pagination__next` selector).

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-ebay-sold-item-csv-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
import pandas as pd

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    
params = {
    '_nkw': 'oakley+sunglasses',      # search query  
    'LH_Sold': '1',                   # shows sold items
    '_pgn': 1                         # page number
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__pl-on-bottom"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        try:
            sold_date = products.select_one(".s-item__title--tagblock .POSITIVE").text
        except:
            sold_date = None
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "sold_date": sold_date
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break
    
# save to CSV (install, import pandas as pd)
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv("ebay_products.csv", index=False)
```

Output:
file is created: "ebay_products.csv"

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os
import pandas as pd

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),      # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key   
    "engine": "ebay",                     # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",            # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "oakley+sunglasses",          # search query
    "LH_Sold": "1"                        # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        title = organic_result.get("title")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break
    
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_csv("ebay_products.csv", index=False)
```

Output:
file is created: "ebay_products.csv"

There's a [13 ways to scrape any public data from any website](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/) blog post if you want to know more about website scraping.

Comment: Hello, I have been playing around with your first solution using BeautifulSoup after some time away from the project, and I cannot get the code to correctly print the sold date in the csv file. Nothing is printed. I also tried chatGPT which didn't work. Can you please help me resolve this issue and correctly print the sold date? Thanks!